# systemLayoutSizeFittingSize vs. sizeThatFits

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have a question about when to use this UIView method `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSisze)targetSize`. Can't this be done with the other method `sizeThatFits`? Particularly I saw some usage of `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:CGSizeZero`, is this the same as `sizeThatFits`?